# How can I combined tables without saving each section as a separate table? An additional column also has to be added and will be different values

Tags: excel, powerquery

The Source Data is janky and currently looks similar to this when uploaded into PowerQuery:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Table does not have column names. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | Null | Null | Null | January Data (This line will be deleted. |
| Facility: | NJ | CA | KY | Locations (This line will be deleted) |
| Input Mat | lbs | lbs | lbs | Units (This line will be deleted) |
| PET | 1000 | 250 | 500 | **KEEP** |
| 2/1/2023 | Null | Null | Null | February Data (This line will be deleted) |
| Facility: | NJ | CA | KY | Locations (This line will be deleted.) |
| Input Mat | lbs | lbs | lbs | Unints (This line will be deleted) |
| PET | 1500 | 150 | 600 | **KEEP** |
| 3/1/2023 | Null | Null | Null | March Data (This line will be want to be deleted) |
| Facility: | NJ | CA | KY | This line will be deleted. |
| Input Mat | lbs | lbs | lbs | This line will be deleted. |
| PET | 2000 | 175 | 750 | **KEEP** |

I want the final table to look like this:

| Date | Material | NJ_Mat | CA_Mat | KY_Mat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | PET | 1000 | 250 | 500 |
| 2/1/2023 | PET | 1500 | 150 | 600 |
| 3/1/2023 | PET | 2000 | 175 | 750 |

I am currently saving each month as a separate table and then making the edits by month which feels very manual because I'm doing them same steps in PowerQuery.

Looking at January for example, the table saved is:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | Null | Null | Null |
| Facility: | NJ | CA | KY |
| Input Mat | lbs | lbs | lbs |
| PET | 1000 | 250 | 500 |

I make the following edits in Power Query and get the below table:

1. Adding a custom column with the date. This is manually added as "01/01/2023". It would be great if it could read the "1/1/2023" in the above data.
2. Renaming Columns
3. Removing top 2 rows

| Date | Material | NJ_Mat | CA_Mat | KY_Mat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | PET | 1000 | 250 | 500 |

This is completed each month by manually typing in the new month (e.g. February would be "02/01/2023") and manually updating the source data as "Feb_Mat", "Mar_Mat", "Apr_Mat" until I get 12 separate updated tables.  After each month is completed and QA'd, then I'm combining all months by appending queries which gives me the final data set that I'm looking for.  This process is very manual and I need some help because I'm very new to PowerQuery.

I was thinking if it was possible to run the steps twelve times automatically and when the iteration is higher, then it calls a different month.  For example, the first run through would get January's data table (Jan_Mat) and update the date to "01/01/23" automatically.  The second run through would get February's data table (Feb_Mat) and update the date to "02/01/23", March would be "Mar_Mat" and "03/01/2023", and so on through December.  Even this would save me a lot of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
AddGroup = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index",{{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 4), Int64.Type}}), //assume groups of 4 rows
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(AddGroup, {"Index"}, {{"data", each 
    let #"Original" = _,
    #"Remove Rows" = Table.AlternateRows(#"Original",0,1,1),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Remove Rows",{"Index"}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Columns"),
    #"Rename" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Promoted Headers",List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"), each _ &"_Mat")})),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Rename, "Date", each #"Original"{0}[Column1],type date),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Facility:_Mat", "Material"}})
in #"Renamed Columns", type table }}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows"[data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data",List.Distinct({"Date","Material"}&List),List.Distinct({"Date","Material"}&List)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Data",{"Index"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", List.Transform(List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns"),{"Date","Material"}),each{_,type number}))
in  #"Changed Type2"
```

[image]